# Flink throughput per task (or node)

Tags: apache-flink

How can I calculate the throughput of a task or node in Flink? The only reference to throughput that I can find in Flink's documentation is related with the [Meter](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/monitoring/metrics.html#meter). But I'm not sure if this does what I need. Can someone confirm if it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flink 1.2 there will be metrics for throughput per task.

In 1.1 you have to build something yourself. You could use this flatMap operator as an example to measure throughput: https://github.com/rmetzger/flink-state-watermarks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dataartisans/utils/ThroughputLogger.java

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually going to target 1.2 so that is good news